# Sed replace if there is no space after pattern

Tags: sed, awk

I need to make SED replace `.` with `.*space*` inside a tag... I did it, but i need to make it just replace IF there is no *space* after the `.` - It will be a patch proccess. 1600 files.

example:

`sed -i -e "/<b>/ {s/\./\. /}" file.txt` will make sed replace `.` with `.*space*`
from this:

`<div class="pontos"><b>TERMINAL V.OFICINAS</b></div>`

to this

`<div class="pontos"><b>TERMINAL V. OFICINAS</b></div>`

but what if in a file, i already have

i need to make sed just replace if there is no space after the dot.

If possible, explain what will act as the "if" in the expression.
Thank you.

PS: awk can be used too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed 's/\.\([^ ]\)/. \1/g' input

 \.\([^ ]\): match a dot followed by a non-space character,
             also remember the non-space character

 . \1      : replace the match with a dot, space, and the
             non-space character
```

Comment: if "a no space char" is after the dot, then the match will not take place; ie the substitution will not happen. is there really a need for a backreference ?

Comment: if there is a non-space character, then you do not want to replace it during substitution. So it is necessary.

Comment: but this is what you are checking to not match. that is what `\.[^ ]` means. replace all occurances of `a dot followed by a no-space`. If the dot is followed by a no-space then the substitution will not take place. I do not see the need for a backreference.

Comment: This is correct for the 'beginning to middle of line' cases.  It doesn't handle a dot at the end of the line; you'll need a second substitution for that (or you need a version of `sed` that supports ERE — extended regular expression — notation and use alternatives).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for sharing, but in my case, there won't be dots at the end of the line :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work even at the end of a line

```
sed 's/\. \{0,1\}/\. /g' input
```